# Find maximum value of time in list containing tuples of time in format ('hour', 'min', 'AM/PM')

Tags: python, list, sorting, datetime, max

I have a list of of tuples that represent different times

```
timeList = [('4', '12', 'PM'), ('8', '23', 'PM'), ('4', '03', 'AM'), ('1', '34', 'AM'), 
('12', '48', 'PM'), ('4', '13', 'AM'), ('11', '09', 'AM'), ('3', '12', 'PM'), 
('4', '10', 'PM')]
```

I want to return the max from the list, after some searching I realized I could use the key in max to search by the AM or PM first.
`print(max(timeList, key = operator.itemgetter(2)))`

When I run this however, I'm getting the wrong max `('4', '12', 'PM')`
 
I thought about it, and not only does it not make sense, given that 8:23 should be max, but I also realized that 12:48 would probably return max since it's a PM and also technically greater than 8 in my search.

That being said, how might I get this max to find the latest possible time, given formatting of the list can not be changed.

Comment: to run the code make sure you include `import operator`

Comment: .itemgetter(2) returns the third element, not the second (offset 0)

Comment: The term you want to use is *"custom sort order, by meridiem (alphabetic descending), then by hour and min (alphanumeric descending)"*

Comment: FYI: ['AM/PM' can either be called 'period' (apparently its standard name) or 'meridiem' (way less ambiguous)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1468857/what-is-am-pm-called)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just define an appropriate key-function. You want `int(hour)`, `int(minute)` and `'PM'` already sorts lexicographically higher than `"AM"`, but it should be considered *first*, so. Also, you need to take the hours modulus 12, so that `12` sorts less than other numbers, within a `pm`/`am`:

```
In [39]: timeList = [('4', '12', 'PM'), ('8', '23', 'PM'), ('4', '03', 'AM'), ('1', '34', 'AM'),
    ...: ('12', '48', 'PM'), ('4', '13', 'AM'), ('11', '09', 'AM'), ('3', '12', 'PM'),
    ...: ('4', '10', 'PM')]

In [40]: def key(t):
...:     h, m, z = t
...:     return z, int(h)%12, int(m)
...:

In [41]: max(timeList,key=key)
Out[41]: ('8', '23', 'PM')
```

But what would make *the most sense* is to actually use `datetime.time` objects, instead of pretending a tuple of strings is a good way to store time.

So something like:

```
In [49]: def to_time(t):
    ...:     h, m, z = t
    ...:     h, m = int(h)%12, int(m)
    ...:     if z  == "PM":
    ...:         h += 12
    ...:     return datetime.time(h, m)
    ...:

In [50]: real_time_list = list(map(to_time, timeList))

In [51]: real_time_list
Out[51]:
[datetime.time(16, 12),
 datetime.time(20, 23),
 datetime.time(4, 3),
 datetime.time(1, 34),
 datetime.time(12, 48),
 datetime.time(4, 13),
 datetime.time(11, 9),
 datetime.time(15, 12),
 datetime.time(16, 10)]

In [52]: list(map(str, real_time_list))
Out[52]:
['16:12:00',
 '20:23:00',
 '04:03:00',
 '01:34:00',
 '12:48:00',
 '04:13:00',
 '11:09:00',
 '15:12:00',
 '16:10:00']
```

Note, now `max` "just works":

```
In [54]: t = max(real_time_list)

In [55]: print(t)
20:23:00
```

And if you need a pretty string to print, just do the formatting at that point:

```
In [56]: print(t.strftime("%I:%M %p"))
08:23 PM
```

Comment: I like this one best, as it solves the problem without using datetime (what i was trying to do for a challenge).

Comment: I have seem many videos and answers in the same format as your juanpa, where you have `In [n]:` and I was wondering how you got those, what IDE you're using.

Comment: @Podo it's not an IDE, it's an enhanced interpreter shell, [`ipython`](https://ipython.org/install.html)

Comment: @Podo it's associated with Jupyter Notebooks, but the enhanced shell by itself is great. Here's some more info: http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/tutorial.html

Comment: Wonderful. So when I use a key function like you've shown as the key in my max, I'm getting an `unexpected EOF while parsing` at the line `max(timeList,key = key) 

I tried passing it timeList as a parameter, like `key = key(timeList)` since I assume that's where function `key` is getting it's argument, but that gives an error as well. 

Thoughts?

Comment: @Podo you almost certainly have forgotten either to close a parenthesis/bracket above that line.

Comment: It was exactly that. What was the giveaway for my own edification?

Comment: @Podo that's what the error message is saying, that the parser reached an unexpected EOF (end of the file), which would happen when brackets are not closed (it keeps reading expecting a closing bracket, but encounters the end of file first).

Comment: @Podo another thing that could cause it, something like this: `for x in range(10):` with no `pass` or for-loop body.

Answer (score 4):

Why not *add* structure to your data?

```
from datetime import datetime

max(datetime.strptime(''.join(x), '%I%M%p') for x in timeList)

# datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 20, 23)
# i.e. 8.23pm
```

While you say "formatting of list should not be changed", that's exactly what all solutions are implicitly doing in order to perform comparisons.

Comment: yeap, looked for this before posting a similar solution.

Comment: @AntonvBR, I upvoted your answer & juanpa's for either implementing or mentioning conversion to dates. It's worrying how so many of us instinctively jump onto the string formatting bandwagon.

Comment: yes I agree, but it is also very common to read the questions literally and forget the fact that the OPs aren't necessarily looking for what they are asking for.

Comment: Hmmm, but to go back to old format you would have to do something like this: `tuple(max(datetime.strptime(''.join(x), '%I%M%p') for x in timeList).strftime('%#I %M %p').split(' '))`, right?

Comment: @AntonvBR, yes if the timestamp also included a timezone, then it would no longer be a simple sort on multiple distinct (string) fields; we'd want to compute the underlying datetime then use it as sort key.

Comment: (Yeah ideally the database should keep a timestamp as a primary key, as say HBASE does)

Answer (score 2):

`key` param with the `max` function is used to notify `max` on which value you want to perform max operation. `itemgetter(2)` fetches the value at 2nd index, and lexicographically "PM" is the highest value in the list at index 2 (lexicographically 'PM' > 'AM'). You may use a *lambda* function to calculate the maximum on tuple at index 0 and 1 as:

```
>>> timeList = [('4', '12', 'PM'), ('8', '23', 'PM'), ('4', '03', 'AM'), ('1', '34', 'AM'), ('12', '48', 'PM'), ('4', '13', 'AM'), ('11', '09', 'AM'), ('3', '12', 'PM'), ('4', '10', 'PM')]

# type-casting it to `int` to avoid incorrect result 
# due lexicographical comparision of `str`
>>> max(timeList, key=lambda x: (x[2], int(x[0]), int(x[1])))
('12', '48', 'PM')            #   ^      ^         ^ Third priority to `int` value of minute
                              #   ^      ^ Second priority to int value of `hour`
                              #   ^ First priority to lexicographically sort on `AM`/`PM`
```

OR, you perform the comparison on [`datetime.datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime) object as:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime

>>> max(timeList, key=lambda x: datetime.strptime('{}:{}{}'.format(*x), '%I:%M%p'))
('8', '23', 'PM')
```

I think you should have created the list of [`datetime.datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime) instead of time `tuples` initially.

Comment: You need to inlcude 'PM'/'AM' in the sort key, or else this will fail: `timeList.append(('12','59','AM'))`

Comment: `pandas` allows doing this automatically (with a MultiIndex), see my answer

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the solutions you can also sort with datetime:

```
from datetime import datetime

timeList = [('4', '12', 'PM'), ('8', '23', 'PM'), ('4', '03', 'AM'), ('1', '34', 'AM'), 
('12', '48', 'PM'), ('4', '13', 'AM'), ('11', '09', 'AM'), ('3', '12', 'PM'), 
('4', '10', 'PM')]

sorted(timeList, key=lambda x: datetime.strptime(''.join(x), '%I%M%p'))[-1]
```

Returns:

```
('8', '23', 'PM')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is really elegantly implemented in pandas, which allows a MultiIndex, which we can then sort on and take the head:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

timeList = [('4','12','PM'),  ('8','23','PM'),  ('4','03','AM'),
            ('1','34','AM'),  ('12','48','PM'), ('4','13','AM'),
            ('11','09','AM'), ('3','12','PM'),  ('4','10','PM')]

timeDf = pd.DataFrame(timeList, columns=['hr','min','meridiem'])
timeDf.set_index(['meridiem','hr','min'], inplace=True, drop=True)

#timeDf['value'] = np.random.randint(1,10, timeDf.shape[0]) # np.nan

timeDf.sort_index(level=0, ascending=False, inplace=True) # sort by meridiem, then the remaining cols (alphanumeric string comparison)
timeDf.index[0]
# ('PM', '8', '23')
```

Notes:

- If you want to keep `hr,min,meridiem` as columns in your df, then use `set_index(..., drop=False)`
- as AntonvBR points out, if the timestamp also included a timezone, then we could no longer use a simple sort on multiple distinct (string) fields; we'd want to compute the underlying datetime then use that as sort key.

Comment: ... what if there's an `('11','49','PM')`? Anyway, why not `timeDf.sort_values(by=['meridiem','hr','min'])`?

Answer (score -1):

looks like you timeList are times.
maybe it makes sense parsing it as such?

```
 max([datetime.strptime("{}:{} {}".format(t[0],t[1],t[2]),'%I:%M %p') for t in timeList]).strftime("%H:%M")
```

Comment: Nice, but you are overcomplicating it (look at jp_data_analysis' answer)